# How do I make an imagemap area clickable with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, imagemap

Minimal, complete example ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lo7cssq5/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <map name="myMap" id="myMap">
            <area shape="rect" coords="10,10,100,100">
        </map>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" usemap="#myMap">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("map#myMap area").click(function () {
                    alert("click!");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What different browsers do when hovering over the upper left-hand corner of the image:

- **Chome**: Shows the "hand" cursor and reacts to clicks (this is the behavior I actually want).
- **Firefox**: Does not show the "hand" cursor, but reacts to clicks.
- **IE** and **Edge**: Neither show the "hand" cursor nor react to clicks.

I know that I can put `href` in the area tag, but it's a highly dynamic site and I'd like to do all sort of jQuery stuff with the area (hover highlight, click handler, etc.). I also know that I can fix Firefox's behavior with `area { cursor: pointer; }`, but that doesn't help with IE and Edge.

Do I have a bug somewhere in my code or is this a bug in IE/Edge?

Comment: Tried with IE11, Edge on a Win 10 PC and both responded to clicks even though the hand cursor wasn't showing up. Behavior in Chrome and FF was same as stated in question. Adding a `href="#"` makes the hand cursor also appear in all the browsers (+ they already responded to clicks). Additionally, the specs say this about the `area` element - *If the area element has no href attribute, then the area represented by the element cannot be selected*. A very strict implementation can infer that as "don't respond to clicks"? I don't know.

Comment: Spec link - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-map-element

Comment: @Harry: Strange. I just tested it again and it seems to work on another machine's Edge, so this might be related to my machine. Will test further, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `href`. And you have to ignore events in the click function. Also, most readable if you give each area an id, or, if some areas respond in the same way, use a class (i.e. `class="areaRed"`)

e.g.

```
<map name="myMap" id="myMap">
 <area id="area1" shape="rect" coords="10,10,100,100" href="#">
</map>
```

and in your click function

```
$("#area1").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  /*
   your code here
  */
});
```